# change javascript array all index

Tags: arrays, csv, arraylist, indexing, key

i want to change the index of all array elements with other array
this array came from csv file and it may be more than 3 columns
the index array is:

```
theheadoptions=[
  "uid",
  "nid",
  "name"
];
```

the main array is:

```
[
  "uid,nid,name",
  "1,28807051203034,q",
  "2,28807051203035,w",
  "3,28807051203036,e",
  "4,28807051203037,r",
  "5,28807051203038,t",
  "6,28807051203039,y",
  "7,28807051203040,u",
  "8,28807051203041,I",
  "9,28807051203042,o",
  "10,28807051203043,p",
  ""
]
```

i want it become

```
[
  {uid:1,nid:28807051203034,name:q},
  {uid:2,nid:28807051203035,name:w},
  {uid:3,nid:28807051203036,name:e|,
  {uid:4,nid:28807051203037,name:r},
  {uid:5,nid:28807051203038,name:t},
  {uid:6,nid:28807051203039,name:y},
  {uid:7,nid:28807051203040,name:u},
  {uid:8,nid:28807051203041,name:I},
  {uid:9,nid:28807051203042,name:o},
  {uid:10,nid:28807051203043,name:p},
]
```

Answer (score -1):

i did it

```
theheadoptions=[
  "uid",
  "nid",
  "name"
];
trs=[
  "uid,nid,name",
  "1,28807051203034,q",
  "2,28807051203035,w",
  "3,28807051203036,e",
  "4,28807051203037,r",
  "5,28807051203038,t",
  "6,28807051203039,y",
  "7,28807051203040,u",
  "8,28807051203041,I",
  "9,28807051203042,o",
  "10,28807051203043,p",
];
for(i=1;i<trs.length-1;i++){
      ndlevel=trs[i].split(splitter);
      dddsss(ndlevel,theadoption);
    } 
function dddsss(arr,heads){
  const obj = {};
  arr.forEach(function(v,k){
    index=k;
    obj[heads[k]]=v;
  });
  console.log(obj);
}
```